# AngularJS display content incorrently

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularJS and want to display the button text from controller property as below:

```
<button>{{object.Text}}</button>
```

the expected result is display button the content is "Submit", but in the ios just display "{{object.Text}}" in the screen. Android or desktop browser is display correctly.

can anyone helps?
thanks.

Comment: can you able to post the code

Answer (score 0):

It will be helpful to you, If you post your code, I will update the code according to your problem.

```js
var app=angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.object={
      Text:"Click Me!....",
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-strict-di ng-controller="testCtrl">
<button > {{object.Text}}</button>
</div>
```